# Pushing app updates to my application via weblink

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have an application and have made some updates to it but I do not know how to push the update out.  I am not using the app store but rather distributing via my server on a weblink.  Is there something I need to add to my code?  Does it delete the previous version of the app and installs the new or does it just update the information within the code?  Any help is greatly appreciated for I am new to this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using app store, you cannot "push" updates, except if you have added this capability in your code beforehand (i.e. support push notifications and send one to ask the users to update).

I assume you're distributing Over-The-Air, if that's the case, just increase the version number of your app, and do the same in your manifest file. After that, you'll have to notify your users that there is an update available (i.e. e-mail them). They can then redownload the app, if the bundle id etc. is still the same and the version number increased, the app will be replaced by the newer version.

Note that, as you can see, if you don't know your users, you won't be able to reach them and inform them of an update. That's one of the reasons people use the AppStore to distribute to "strangers".

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was the help I needed.  You guys are so helpful here.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Dbrown if my answer helped you, please accept it to minimize the number of unsolved questions here. Thanks.